# How can I force the Route with .html and id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I wanna force the `Route` with .html and a 32 length id.

For example, here is the URL:

```
https://localhost:44331/Re/test.html?id=12345678901234567890123456789012
```

I want it when there is no id parameter in the URL or the length of id is not 32, it returns 404 status code.

Here is the controller:

```
namespace V.Controllers
{
    [Route("Re/")]
    public class ReController : Controller
    {
        [Route("test.html{id:length(32)}")]
        public IActionResult test(string id)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

After I ran the code, it always reports 404 status code.

What's wrong with my route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can specify query string parameters in the route. Try validating the `id` in the action, or if you can change the route, add it as an additional segment.

```cs
    [Route("Re/")]
    public class ReController : Controller
    {
        [Route("test.html")]
        public IActionResult test(string id)
        {
            if (id == null || id.Length != 32)
                return NotFound();

            return Json(new {id= id});
        }

        [Route("test2.html/{id:length(32)}")]
        public IActionResult test2(string id)
        {
            return Json(new {id= id});
        }
    }
```

See: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: I tried the second way(test2.html) you provided by the URL:https://localhost:44331/Re/test2.html/id=12345678901234567890123456789012 . It still can not work.

Comment: You don't need the `id=` part of the URL. try this https://localhost:44331/Re/test2.html/12345678901234567890123456789012